# How to use generator method in django template?

Tags: python, django

I want to use python generators in django template, Is it possible?

For example, I have model and it contains generator object as shown bellow,

```
class TestMe(models.Model):
    @property
    def gen(self):
        yield 1
        yield 2
```

context['gen'] = gen

then in template,

```
  {{ gen }} # it should be print 1
  {{ gen }} # it should be print 2
```

Without using for loop

I have tried this way but it returns the python generator not 1. Any one have idea about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In template

```
{{ gen.next }}
{{ gen.next }}
```

Comment: Good answer! Unforturnately, this won't work in Python 3, where you call `next(gen)` instead of `gen.next()`.

Comment: Indeed, answer by dhana is much better and solved my problem.

Answer (score 6):

I have used the custom filter,

```
@register.filter(name='dj_iter')
def dj_iter(gen):
    try:
       return next(gen)
    except StopIteration:
       return 'Completed Iteration'
```

In django template, I used the filter

```
{{ gen|dj_iter }}
```

Answer (score 2):

A generator returns an iterable, so you can loop over it.

In Python:

```
for value in context.gen:
    print(value)
```

Or in the Django template:

```
{% for value in context.gen %}
{{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: it's bit tricky, two code blocks are different places. I want use this one in two code blocks. without using for loop I want to use generator in django.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do, please update your question with more details.

Comment: I have updated, I can't use for loop in django template. I need to iterate gen object like ``next`` without for loop

Comment: EchoUA Team's answer will work in Python 2. For Python 3, I think you'll have to write a custom template tag.

Comment: Yeah I written custom filter.

Comment: @dhana  , I am having this same issue. How did you solve with custom filter?

Comment: @Mir I answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33632624/how-to-use-generator-method-in-django-template/40701031#40701031