# Variable not reassigned in Django template

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I am trying to reassign a variable in a for-loop. Depending on the value, I will proceed to do other things, before resetting it to another default.

However, the value is not being replaced properly within the loop.

These are my template tags:

```
@register.filter
def addition(val1, val2):
    return val1 + val2

@register.simple_tag
def assignVar(arg1):
    return arg1
```

Here is a portion of my full template

```
{% assignVar 50 as testVar %}
<table>
   <tbody>
   {% for data in LIST %}
   <tr>
      A: {{testVar}}
      {% assignVar testVar|addition:20 as testVar %}
      B: {{testVar}}
      {% if testVar > 150 %}
         {{data}}
         {% assignVar 0 as testVar %}
      {% endif %}
   </tr>
   {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

My output is as such:

```
A: 50
B: 70
A: 50
B: 70
A: 50
B: 70
...
```

Why does my `testVar` value not increase?
Each time it loops, the `testVar` variable keeps going back to the initial value instead of being replaced with the new one.

This was what I expected:

```
A: 50
B: 70
A: 70
B: 90
A: 90
B: 110
...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Template - Increment the value of a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659560/django-template-increment-the-value-of-a-variable)

Comment: Er...not really. I cant really use the `forloop.counter` as `testVar` is not just used there(its used in multiple for-loops). My issue is more similar to the comment to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8659866/13547487

Comment: The answer from Eduardo that iklinac linked to is still the case, many years on - I don't whether it's possible to write a template tag that assigns values reliably, but it's not the recommended approach in Django. For the example in your question, I would create a generator, pass an iterable to the view, then using a custom filter as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40701031/113962).